# RegExp css url pattern group

Tags: javascript, css, regex, actionscript-3

I have the following css strings that I am trying to parse using a RegExp.  I understand how to split on the comma.  How do I work with the result to return an array or string?

I guess I'm missing the concept of capturing groups.  These are css background properties.

this will split the commas `/,\s*/` how would I then split the spaces to return a 2d array.

```
value = "0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 50% 50%";
```

This works great to get the first url.  I would like to split on the comma /,\s*/  then split that result with `/((?<=\")[^\"]*(?=\"))/`

```
value = 'url("img/army_ant.png"),url("img/ants_menuNavButtton.png"),url("img/dirtbgtile.png")';
```

Thanks.

I am working in AS3 but JavaScript RegExp work just as well.

Thanks

Comment: for regex questions, explicit examples of input, expected output are the most helpful.

Comment: JS does not support look-behinds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` function. For the first case:

```
var value = "0% 100%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 50% 50%";
var final = value.split(/,\s*/).map(function(e) { return e.split(/\s+/); })
```